# In Firebase Dynamic linking via Fcm, it just opens the app rather than going to activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-dynamic-links

In Firebase Dynamic linking via Fcm the link directs me to activity only when the app is open if closed and I click on the notification; it just opens the app

```
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="www.example.com" android:path="/book" android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:host="www.example.com" android:path="/book" android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

BooksActivity.java

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                       //Getting the id from notification dynamic linking
                        bookId= MyFirebaseMessagingService.BOOK_ITEM_ID;
                    }
                    if (deepLink != null) {
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                                "Found deep link!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "getDynamicLink: no link found");
                    }
                }

            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                }
            });
```

//Thanks in advance

Comment: You are creating notification in your app or you are using system default notifcation?

Comment: Thank you for responding.
I'm using firebase cloud messaging and I figured onMessageReceived is not called when app is in background

Comment: can you show how you are generating push notification. You are using notification message or data message.